# How to make a function in one class implement another class?

Tags: python, class, function, add-in, arcgis

I am creating a GUI with a code like this:

```
    class MyClass2(QtGui.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self, win_parent = None):


        def on_blahblah_clicked(x):


    if __name__ == "__main__":
         # Someone is launching this directly
         # Create the QApplication
          app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
         #The Main window
         main_window = HyperlinkWindow()
         main_window.show()
# Enter the main loop
app.exec_()
```

And I have a code for an add-in button like this:

```
    class MyClass(object):
        """Impementation of Some_addin.button (Button)"""
        def __init__(self):
            #Code here
        def onClick(self):
            # Code
            pass
```

I want to create an add-in button that when clicked it brings out the GUI created above. So I want to be able to call the class of the GUI code, MyClass2 in function onClick. Just like I do with a in y in the code below:

```
    class x:
        a = 1 + 1
    class y:
        print x.a
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make much sense to me. What is "runs the class, MyClass2"? What exactly do you want to do in `onClick`?

Comment: Since you are using Qt, perhaps signals and slots can solve your problem.

Comment: "function in one class implement another class" has no meaning. What do you mean by run or implement MyClass2? do you mean instantiate like `a = MyClass2()`?

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope this time I am more clear.

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: I need help on how to do that in this case...

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I have figured out how to do it now. I only have a problem of ArcGIS crashing when I whenever I run this using the addin...